# How to enter recovery/download mode with broken home button and broken bootloader

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-note

I was trying to install [NightOwl cm12.1 Android 5.1.1 Beta 5 build for my Galaxy Note 1 N7000](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note/development/rom-t2938649). I followed all the installation instruction on that ROM's thread. [I flashed philz CWM 5.15.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61030901&postcount=4086). And now I'm stuck at step 4 after flashing the new kernel (6.48.4) to get updated CWM recovery. Now, my phone is unbootable stuck in the n7000 screen. If I wait just a little longer, the phone would just turned off. The installation guide says that I could still enter recovery mode by pressing "home" and "volume+" and "power" buttons. But unfortunately, my hardware home button is broken.

I read somewhere that we could still enter recovery/download mode via ADB. I've tried it with no luck. It can't find the device (since it won't turned on). Is there any other way for me to at least enter download mode to reflash it back to the original stock rom via odin?

Comment: Can you still boot to the ROM?

Comment: Step - 1: Read ALL Instruction before doing risky things. You know your Home is broken.  So you cannot flash this ROM.
Have you tried to enter fastboot or Bootloader mode or flashmode? for my device its to plug in the usb while holding Volume+ key. For now, try all the combinations of hardware keys and see it any works.
And Remember "If Your Phone Is Truly Bricked: Take It Into the Store and Play Dumb" :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samsung devices can usually be forced into download mode using a [JIG](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/need-a-samsung-usb-jig-build-your-own/). They are pretty simple and cheap to make. If your device has been soft-bricked this will almost always work.

http://www.xda-developers.com/need-a-samsung-usb-jig-build-your-own/

Answer (score 2):

Use ADB, there is a command on there to reboot your phone to Odin/download mode, it's `adb reboot download`.

Answer (score 1):

Jig or ADB. Not sure if ADB would work though, if you can't hardly turn on the device. I would consider trying it first, because it's easy and you have nothing but some time to lose, but I'll bet you'll end up using a jig (can be made or bought).